# Setting a `NULL` default for a parameter in Rcpp function

Tags: rcpp

I want to set the default value of a parameter to `NULL` in an `Rcpp` function and do some calculation based on the parameter if the parameter is not `NULL`. An example of such a code would be

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test_null(Nullable<DataFrame> p1 = R_NilValue){

  if(p1.isNull()){
    NumericMatrix T(2,2);
    Rcout << T << std::endl;
  }
    else{
    NumericMatrix T(p1.nrow());
    Rcout << T << std::endl;
  }
  return (42);
}
```

However, I am not able to compile this function and am getting an error message

`error: no member named 'nrow' in 'Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::DataFrame_Impl<PreserveStorage> >'`

which tells me that there is no `nrow` defined for a `Nullable DataFrame`. Is there any other way to do implement a default `NULL` value for a parameter (i.e., a `DataFrame`) in `Rcpp` so that I can calculate other properties (no. or rows, columns etc.) of the `DataFrame` when it is not `NULL`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks you!

SN248

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close.  You missed one instantiation: a `Nullable<>` is not yet the same as its template type---we need to create an object first.

So here is your code with corrected whitespace ;-) and the missing line plus a test invocation of each case:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test_null(Nullable<DataFrame> p1 = R_NilValue){

  if (p1.isNull()) {
    NumericMatrix T(2,2);
    Rcout << T << std::endl;
  } else {
    DataFrame S(p1);
    NumericMatrix T(S.nrow());
    Rcout << T << std::endl;
  }
  return (42);
}

/*** R
test_null(NULL)
test_null(data.frame(a=1:3, b=letters[1:3]))
*/
```

For which I get the expected result:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/61701367/answer.cpp")

R> test_null(NULL)
0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000

[1] 42

R> test_null(data.frame(a=1:3, b=letters[1:3]))
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000

[1] 42
R>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dirk!  Yes, I wasn't aware of the instantiation part and couldn't find it in a previous response to a similar question. Just to add - keep your videos coming, we love them!

Comment: It's tricky with code like that. There is _simply too much to document_ :-/.  I remembered that we used it in [mvabund](https://github.com/aliceyiwang/mvabund) so I (literally) looked at an example there.  And I checked: we have none at the Rcpp Gallery. [We almost surely do in the unit tests though. _Always_ check those!] Do you want to take your question (and almost complete answer) and slap some Markdown around for a proper submission at the Rcpp Gallery?  And thanks so much for the thumbs up on the videos!

Comment: Thank you the unit test pointer. I would love to do a Rcpp Gallery submission for this question!

Comment: Great!  Let me know if you need help.  The setup is older and uses Jekyll.  You can just submit an .Rmd file, or, if you prefer, a .cpp with the markdown embedded.  Happy to help, maybe poke me over there or over email.  And please post with a real name (as you do anyway in your CRAN package, which I am still impressed by).